# Operator overloading "equal to"

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to overload equal to "=" operator in C++ for

```
class Array
{
    int *p;
    int len;
};
```

All functions/constructor etc. are defined.

My question: 
Could someone give me the prototype of the operator overloaded function?
And suppose:

```
Array a,b;
b=a;
```

Which of "a" and "b" would be passed implicitly and which explicitly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The **equal-to** operator is `operator==`, not `operator=`. What you want is the **assignment** operator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Comment: My bad. :P assignment operator. not equal to :)

Answer (score 1):

The prototype is `Array& operator=(const Array& that)`.

While implementing this, remember about the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and make good use of the [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).

Answer (score 0):

There is probably more than one way to do it, but here is an option.

**Public Functions:**

```
Array::Array(const Array& array)
{
    Allocate(0);
    *this = array;
}

Array::~Array()
{
    Deallocate();
}

const Array& Array::operator=(const Array& array)
{
    if (this == &array)
        return *this;

    Deallocate();
    Allocate(array.len);

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
        p[i] = array.p[i];

    return *this;
}
```

**Non-Public Functions:**

```
void Array::Allocate(int size)
{
    len = size;
    if (len > 0)
        p = new int[len];
}

void Array::Deallocate()
{
    if (len > 0)
        delete[] p;
    len = 0;
}
```

Of course, you can always use a `vector<int>` instead...

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the *assignment operator =* (**not** equal-to, which is `operator==` and usually serves as an equality comparison)

```
class Array
{
    int *p;
    int len;

public:
    // Assignment operator, remember that there's an implicit 'this' parameter
    Array& operator=(const Array& array)
    {
        // Do whatever you want
        std::cout << "assignment called";

        return *this;
    }
};


int main(void) {

    Array a, b;

    a = b;
}
```

remember that since you wrote "*All functions/constructor etc. are defined*" you should pay attention to what you need your class to do and possibly also implement destructor as in the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) (and/or take a look at its variants in C++11, might be relevant since there's no other code posted).